# Issue in dropdownlist within gridview

Tags: c#, gridview, drop-down-menu

How too add a dropdownlist to gridview and how to add a datasource to dropdown?

For example:

I have gridview with 5 colomns c1,c2,c3,c4,c5 here I want to add a dropdownlist only 
 c1 and c2  what is the procedure for do this work?

note: vs2008,asp.net with c#

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the columns in the GridView and set those two to be TemplateColumns, then put a DropDownList called DropDownList1 in the TemplateColumn.  Then as Hunter says use the DataBound event to bind to say a dataset like so:

```
DropDownList list = e.Item.FindControl("DropDownList1");
list.DataSource = < your DataSet here>;
list.DataValueField = "code";
list.DataTextField = "description";
list.DataBind();
```

Comment: i am writing code like this by your instructions
error will occur pls help
error is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
in the line of --list.DataSource = ds;--
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
  SqlCommand cmp = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from Projectcodetable ", conn);
 SqlDataAdapter dr = new SqlDataAdapter(cmp);
 dr.Fill(ds);
DropDownList list = DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList1");
list.DataSource = ds;
list.DataValueField = "ProjectCode";
list.DataTextField = "ProjectCode";
list.DataBind();
conn.Close();

Comment: My guess is it hasn't found the control DropDownList1.  I'd debug through your code and see where it is failing.  Probably "list" is null.

Did you add the template column?  Without doing the above code and populating the dropdownlists, if you run the page do the dropdowns display?